# Consulta Veículo pela Placa no site sinesp via PHP - sem captcha

Tags: php

Alguém conseguiu fazer a consulta ao Sinesp, via php ?
Estou tentando colocar este código para funcionar porém sem sucesso.

```
  $placa   = 'KCK2486';
  $request = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes" ?><soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" ><soap:Header><dispositivo>GT-S1312L</dispositivo><nomeSO>Android</nomeSO><versaoAplicativo>1.1.1</versaoAplicativo><versaoSO>4.1.4</versaoSO><aplicativo>aplicativo</aplicativo><ip>177.206.169.90</ip><token>5021719229f7ddad0c786542da534ad0375f021f</token><latitude>-3.6770324</latitude><longitude>-38.6791411</longitude></soap:Header><soap:Body><webs:getStatus xmlns:webs="http://soap.ws.placa.service.sinesp.serpro.gov.br/"><placa>'.$placa.'</placa></webs:getStatus></soap:Body></soap:Envelope>';


  $header = array(
    "Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8",
    "Accept: text/plain, */*; q=0.01",
    "Cache-Control: no-cache",
    "Pragma: no-cache",
    "x-wap-profile: http://wap.samsungmobile.com/uaprof/GT-S7562.xml",
    "Content-length: ".strlen($request),
    "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; U; Android 4.1.4; pt-br; GT-S1162L Build/IMM76I) AppleWebKit/534.30 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Mobile Safari/534.30",
  );

  $soap_do = curl_init();
  curl_setopt($soap_do, CURLOPT_URL, "http://sinespcidadao.sinesp.gov.br/sinesp-cidadao/ConsultaPlacaNovo27032014" );
  curl_setopt($soap_do, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 10);
  curl_setopt($soap_do, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT,        10);
  curl_setopt($soap_do, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
  curl_setopt($soap_do, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
  curl_setopt($soap_do, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
  curl_setopt($soap_do, CURLOPT_POST,           true );
  curl_setopt($soap_do, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,     $soap_request);
  curl_setopt($soap_do, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,     $header);
  $res = curl_exec($soap_do);
  if($res === false)
  {
    $err = 'Curl erro: ' . curl_error($soap_do);
    curl_close($soap_do);
    print $err;
  }
  else
  {
    echo $res;
    curl_close($soap_do);
    print 'Ocorreu um erro...';
  }
```

O código acima não funcionou, ou não consegui fazê-lo funcionar e estou investindo agora no código abaixo que, igual ao outro, também não está funcionando, porém parece ser menos complexo.
Podem me ajudar a identificar os erros deste ?

```
<?

$placa = 'ABC1234';

//chave do service
$chave = 'shienshenlhq';
//token para funcionamento
$token = hash_hmac('sha1', $placa, $chave, false);
//ramdom de ip para dificultar rastreamento
$random_ip = (string)mt_rand(1,255).".".mt_rand(0,255).".".mt_rand(0,255).".".mt_rand(0,255);

//criação estática de um xml com as informacoes para resgate
$data = 'GT-S1312L';
$data .= 'Android';
$data .= '1.1.1';
$data .= '4.1.4';
$data .= 'aplicativo';
$data .= '' . $random_ip . '';
$data .= '' . $token . '';
$data .= '' . (( 20000/111000.0 * sqrt(rand(1,1000)) ) * sin(2 * 3.141592654 * rand(1,1000)) + -38.5290245) . '';
$data .= '' . (( 20000/111000.0 * sqrt(rand(1,1000)) ) * cos(2 * 3.141592654 * rand(1,1000)) + -3.7506985) . '';
$data .= '' . $placa . '';

//inicia curl
$ch = curl_init();
//define para onde serao enviados
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://sinespcidadao.sinesp.gov.br/sinesp-cidadao/ConsultaPlacaNovo27032014');
//define que o conteúdo obtido deve ser retornado em vez de exibido
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
//define que recebera posts
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
//define os campos a serem postados
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
//envia
$retorno_curl = curl_exec($ch);
//encerra
curl_close($ch);

//retira o a tag return e seu conteudo, será enviado para retorno[0]
if(preg_match('/\(.*?)\/', utf8_encode($retorno_curl), $retorno)){

    $dom = new DOMDocument();
    //coloca o conteudo da tag return para ser tratado como xml
    $dom->loadXML($retorno[0]);
    //converte seu conteudo como objeto
    $elemento = simplexml_import_dom($dom);
    echo $elemento;

}else{

    echo "ERRO!";

}
```

Comment: Nenhum progresso ate o momento.

Comment: Eles colocaram captcha na consulta do site. Se não existir um API específica você não conseguirá consultar a partir do PHP.

Comment: Mas dessa forma estou simulando o aplicativo

Comment: E como vai preencher o captcha?

Comment: Achei interessante vou acompanhar, e tentar lhe ajudar, vou tentar uns códigos se tiver algum progresso lhe informo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Funcionando de acordo com o GitHub: https://github.com/chapeupreto/sinesp 
Todo crédito ao criador desse código, estou apenas repassando.

**Instalação**: 
`composer require chapeupreto/sinesp`
**Utilização**:

```
<?php

require 'vendor/autoload.php';

use Sinesp\Sinesp;

$veiculo = new Sinesp;

try {
    $veiculo->buscar('GWW-6471');
    if ($veiculo->existe()) {
        print_r($veiculo->dados());
        echo 'O ano do veiculo eh ' , $veiculo->anoModelo, PHP_EOL;
    }
} catch (\Exception $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

O método `buscar()` deve ser o primeiro método a ser invocado. Esse método é empregado para localizar informações do veiculo com a placa informada.

Após a chamada ao método `buscar()`, o método `dados()` irá retornar um array associativo contendo todas as informações do veículo.

Ainda, ao invés de utilizar todo o array retornado pelo método `dados()`, pode-se também recuperar uma informação isoladamente acessando-a como atributo do objeto:

```
echo 'O municipio do veiculo é ', $veiculo->municipio;
```

Answer (score 7):

resolvi, o cara lá do site passou as dicas certinho, só faltou dar as lapidadas... segue o código exemplo que testei desse jeito e funcionou

```
    <?php
  // Desenvolvido Para fins EDUCATIVOS.
  // Criado em 12/11/2014
  // Contato: putyoe@hotmail.com
  $placa   = 'KCK2486';
  $token = hash_hmac('sha1', $placa, 'shienshenlhq', false);
  $request = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes" ?>'
          . '<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" '
          . 'xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" '
          . 'xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" >'
          . '<soap:Header>'
          . '<dispositivo>GT-S1312L</dispositivo>'
          . '<nomeSO>Android</nomeSO>'
          . '<versaoAplicativo>1.1.1</versaoAplicativo><versaoSO>4.1.4</versaoSO>'
          . '<aplicativo>aplicativo</aplicativo><ip>177.206.169.90</ip>'
          . '<token>'.$token.'</token>'
          . '<latitude>-3.6770324</latitude><longitude>-38.6791411</longitude></soap:Header><soap:Body><webs:getStatus xmlns:webs="http://soap.ws.placa.service.sinesp.serpro.gov.br/"><placa>'.$placa.'</placa></webs:getStatus></soap:Body></soap:Envelope>';


  $header = array(
    "Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8",
    "Accept: text/plain, */*; q=0.01",
    "Cache-Control: no-cache",
    "Pragma: no-cache",
    "x-wap-profile: http://wap.samsungmobile.com/uaprof/GT-S7562.xml",
    "Content-length: ".strlen($request),
    "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; U; Android 4.1.4; pt-br; GT-S1162L Build/IMM76I) AppleWebKit/534.30 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Mobile Safari/534.30",
  );

  $soap_do = curl_init();
  curl_setopt($soap_do, CURLOPT_URL, "http://sinespcidadao.sinesp.gov.br/sinesp-cidadao/ConsultaPlacaNovo27032014" );
  curl_setopt($soap_do, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 10);
  curl_setopt($soap_do, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT,        10);
  curl_setopt($soap_do, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
  curl_setopt($soap_do, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
  curl_setopt($soap_do, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
  curl_setopt($soap_do, CURLOPT_POST,           true );
  curl_setopt($soap_do, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $request);
  curl_setopt($soap_do, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,     $header);
  $res = curl_exec($soap_do);
  if($res === false)
  {
    $err = 'Curl erro: ' . curl_error($soap_do);
    curl_close($soap_do);
    print $err;
  }
  else
  {
    echo $res;
    curl_close($soap_do);
    print 'Ocorreu um erro...';
  }
```

> https://paoloo.wordpress.com/2014/03/05/minha-primeira-tentativa-de-decodificar-um-apk-android-e-usar-seu-servico/

**nota:** bgastaldi obrigado pelos esclarecimentos

Comment: FUNCIONANDO PERFEITAMENTE. Me quebrou um galho danado isso.

Comment: Excelente! funcionou corretamente.

Comment: E já mudaram de novo o endpoint, como era de se esperar :)

Comment: Mudaram realmente. Estou tentando conseguir a nova forma. Qd tiver resultado posto

Comment: Parou de funcionar devido à atualização no sinesp para v3.. Alguém sabe o que fazer?

Answer (score 4):

"Galera depois de o apk descompilado entendi o novo método que usaram para ofuscar o novo soap disponível o https://sinespcidadao.sinesp.gov.br/sinesp-cidadao/ConsultaPlacaNovo a chave é a mesma ! Apenas Altera o link para este e pronto !"

Créditos: Junior Kaibro

Novo Código:

```
<?php
  $placa   = 'KCK2486';
  $token = hash_hmac('sha1', $placa, 'shienshenlhq', false);
  $request = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes" ?>'
          . '<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" '
          . 'xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" '
          . 'xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" >'
          . '<soap:Header>'
          . '<dispositivo>GT-S1312L</dispositivo>'
          . '<nomeSO>Android</nomeSO>'
          . '<versaoAplicativo>1.1.1</versaoAplicativo><versaoSO>4.1.4</versaoSO>'
          . '<aplicativo>aplicativo</aplicativo><ip>177.206.169.90</ip>'
          . '<token>'.$token.'</token>'
          . '<latitude>-3.6770324</latitude><longitude>-38.6791411</longitude></soap:Header><soap:Body><webs:getStatus xmlns:webs="http://soap.ws.placa.service.sinesp.serpro.gov.br/"><placa>'.$placa.'</placa></webs:getStatus></soap:Body></soap:Envelope>';


  $header = array(
    "Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8",
    "Accept: text/plain, */*; q=0.01",
    "Cache-Control: no-cache",
    "Pragma: no-cache",
    "x-wap-profile: http://wap.samsungmobile.com/uaprof/GT-S7562.xml",
    "Content-length: ".strlen($request),
    "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; U; Android 4.1.4; pt-br; GT-S1162L Build/IMM76I) AppleWebKit/534.30 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Mobile Safari/534.30",
  );

  $soap_do = curl_init();
  curl_setopt($soap_do, CURLOPT_URL, "http://sinespcidadao.sinesp.gov.br/sinesp-cidadao/ConsultaPlacaNovo");
  curl_setopt($soap_do, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 10);
  curl_setopt($soap_do, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT,        10);
  curl_setopt($soap_do, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
  curl_setopt($soap_do, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
  curl_setopt($soap_do, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
  curl_setopt($soap_do, CURLOPT_POST,           true );
  curl_setopt($soap_do, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $request);
  curl_setopt($soap_do, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,     $header);
  $res = curl_exec($soap_do);
  if($res === false)
  {
    $err = 'Curl erro: ' . curl_error($soap_do);
    curl_close($soap_do);
    print $err;
  }
  else
  {
    echo $res;
    curl_close($soap_do);
    print 'Ocorreu um erro...';
  }
```

Comment: Parou novamente. Aguardando nova solução !

Answer (score 2):

Resolvido e funcionando novamente. 
Explicado passo a passo: 
https://github.com/victor-torres/sinesp-client

**SINESP Client**

SINESP Client torna possível a consulta da base de dados do SINESP Cidadão sem a necessidade do preenchimento de captchas ou algum outro tipo de autenticação.

O que é o SINESP

SINESP Cidadão é uma base de dados pública de veículos brasileiros. É muito útil para identificar carros ou motos roubados ou suspeitos.

Informações disponíveis

Se um veículo com a placa especificada for encontrado, o servidor irá retornar as seguintes informações que serão repassadas através de um dicionário:

```
return_code (código de retorno)
return_message (mensagem de retorno)
status_code (código do status)
status_message (mensagem do status)
chassis (chassi do veículo)
model (modelo/versão)
brand (marca/fabricante)
color (cor/pintura)<br>
year (ano de fabricação)
model_year (ano do modelo)
plate (placa)
date (data e horada consulta)
city (cidade)
state (estado ou unidade federativa)
```

**Por que fazer um cliente do SINESP?**

Não sabemos o porquê, mas o governo não mantém uma API pública para este serviço. A única maneira de acessar os dados é acessando o site do SINESP e respondendo a perguntas de verificação (captchas) para cada uma das requisições.

**O que nós fizemos**

Felizmente as aplicações para Android e iOS permitem que a busca seja feita sem que seja preciso responder a nenhum teste captcha. Nós então fizemos uma engenharia reversa no aplicativo para que pudéssemos ter acesso a essas informações públicas sem que fosse preciso responder a esses captchas chatos.

**Utilizando**

Instalando

Através do PyPI

```
`pip install sinesp-client`
```

Ou a partir do código-fonte

```
`python setup.py install`
```

Utilização normal

```
from sinesp_client import SinespClient
sc = SinespClient()
result = sc.search('ABC1234')
```

**Com proxy**

O SINESP pode bloquear conexões vindas de fora do país. Se acontecer de você estar enfrentando problemas de conexões você pode tentar utilizar um web proxy (SOCKS5), que podem ser encontrados gratuitamente na Internet.

```
from sinesp_client import SinespClient
sc = SinespClient(proxy_address='127.0.0.1', proxy_port=8080)
result = sc.search('ABC1234')
```

Nota: Utilize valores de endereço e porta válidos.

Chamando um script Python através do PHP

Atendendo a diversos pedidos que vêm chegando por e-mail, neste artigo na Wiki do projeto ensino a chamar um script simples feito em Python, que retorna os dados obtidos em formato JSON, e a acessar os dados obtidos através do PHP.

**Como executar o código Python no PHP**

Muita gente me perguntou como obter os resultados gerados pela biblioteca Python do SINESP Client no PHP.

Aqui descrevo como chamar um script simples em Python (baseado no exemplo que tem no README da nossa biblioteca) para enviar os dados obtidos em formato JSON para nossa aplicação em PHP, onde iremos receber e utilizar da melhor forma possível.

**Instalando a biblioteca**

Lembre-se de instalar a biblioteca com

```
pip install sinesp-client
```

Escrevendo o script em Python

Vamos criar um script chamado placa.py, que será executado em linha de comando e receberá a placa do veículo como primeiro argumento:

```
import json
import sys

from sinesp_client import SinespClient

sc = SinespClient()
plate = sys.argv[1]
result = sc.search(plate)
json_result = json.dumps(result)
print(json_result)
```

Escrevendo o script PHP

Para chamar/executar nosso script em Python a partir do PHP e retomar os resultados é bem simples também:

Cuidado com o comando shell_exec, ele deixa seu código suscetível a injections de código malicioso.

```
  $placa = 'M**4***';
  $informacoesDaPlacaEmJSON = shell_exec('python placa.py ' . $placa);
  $informacoesDaPlaca = json_decode($informacoesDaPlacaEmJSON);
```

O objeto gerado

Se a gente imprimir o objeto gerado com a função print_r do PHP:

```
print_r($informacoesDaPlaca);
```

Nós obtemos:

```
stdClass Object
(
    [city] => GUARAMIRIM
    [model_year] => 201*
    [plate] => M**4***
    [color] => VERMELHA
    [status_code] => 0
    [brand] => FIAT/SIENA EL FLEX
    [return_code] => 0
    [date] => 23/02/2016 19:59:59
    [state] => SC
    [chassis] => ************57158
    [year] => 201*
    [return_message] => Sem erros.
    [model] => FIAT/SIENA EL FLEX
    [status_message] => Sem restrição
)
```

Alguns dados foram omitidos.

Acessando os resultados individuais

Isso permite que você também possa acessar os dados assim:

```
print($informacoesDaPlaca->city);
print($informacoesDaPlaca->state);
```

O que retornaria:

```
GUARAMIRIM
SC
```

Comment: Olá Pedro, será que, além do link, poderia adicionar as informações na resposta? Um **paste/cole** já serviria. Isso é que vai que alterem uma letra no nome do repositório... Se o link ficar desativado, sua resposta estaria inválida. Caso não puder fazer isso agora, se me permitir, posso editar e adicionar as informações para você. Mas isso fica a seu critério.

Comment: Feito, lembrarei de fazer das proximas vezes.
Valeeeu

Comment: Apenas dei uma editada na formatação, mas com a informação aí ficou bem melhor a sua resposta, parabéns.