# Como obter dados da Receita Federal?

Tags: libcurl

No site [situação cadastral](http://situacaocadastral.com.br) é possível consultar CPF/CNPJ sem passar por *captcha*, também não pede data de nascimento. Como isso é possível?

Comment: *Contato: falecom@situacaocadastral.com.br*

Comment: @DontVoteMeDown Legal acha mesmo que o cara vai falar como foi feito isso?

Comment: ah, esse caso que linkei já foi solucionado em php [aqui](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/58860/consulta-ve%C3%ADculo-pela-placa-no-site-sinesp-via-php/72403#72403) no SOPT